# How to use divs instead of tables

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the following table layout, but I want to use DIV instead of TABLE:

```
------------------
|       |        |
| CELL1 |  CELL2 |
|       |        |
|       |--------|
|       |        |
|       |  CELL3 |
|       |        |
------------------
```

I want the height of all the cells to be set by their content (i.e. no height: style)

I have tried using float:left on cell1, but can't seem to get cells 2 and 3 to behave.

**EDIT** 
JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/utZR3/

HTML:

```
<div class="list-row">
    <div class="list-left">CELL1
    </div>
    <div class="list-right">
        <div class="list-title">CELL2</div>
        <div class="list-filters">CELL3

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="list-row">
    <div class="list-left">CELL1
    </div>
    <div class="list-right">
        <div class="list-title">CELL2</div>
        <div class="list-filters">CELL3

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="list-row">
    <div class="list-left">CELL1
    </div>
    <div class="list-right">
        <div class="list-title">CELL2</div>
        <div class="list-filters">CELL3

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list-row {
    background:#f4f4f4;
    border:2px solid red;
}

.list-left {
    width:auto;
    padding:10px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.list-right {
    top:0px;
    left:60px;
    padding:10px;
     border:2px solid green;
}
.list-title {

    font-size:18px;
    padding:8px;

}
.list-filters {
    padding:8px;

}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice drawing, any code? :)

Comment: no HTML structure nor CSS.You should  show us what you tried

Comment: I believe, that left cell extends cells on the right by Y axis, and with a width-s, dependent on contents this is possible only with tables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `inline-block` and `float`: here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utZR3/1/)**

```
.list-row {
    background:#f4f4f4;
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid red;}

.list-left {
    width:auto;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid blue;}

.list-right {
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
    border:2px solid green;}
```

Also, since you're not using `relative` or `absolute` positioning, you don't need to specify `top` and `left`.

Comment: Also, take a look at CSS word-wrap; just in case someone types 1000 characters with no spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zV3bN/1/))

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell" id="cell1"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="cell2"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="cell3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{overflow:hidden; width:100%;}
.cell{width:50%; float:right;}
#cell1{float:left;}
```

Your approach (which places the `div`s in rows) is not a good choice in this case.. mine separates them by columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`. Just set widths of about 50% (adjust depending on padding, margins and borders) for the left and right containers and make them inline-block.

[Here is my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuRH2/)

Answer (score 1):

rowspan is not avalaible for display:table,
but you can still use it to get close to what you are looking for.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kqDab
`display:inline-table` used for the show , so they stand aside each others. you can turn it back to `display:table`.

Options i see here is to set an height to parent container to have height:XX% avalaible for direct childs element (if it is: float, inline-block, table ...) . 
Other option is vertical-align middle for the cell if `display:table-cell;`.

You HTML with the same CSS of first demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvlsG

---

**edit** `display:flex` is also a good option nowdays :http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBjqXJ

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
} 
</style>
<div class="grid-container">
   <div class="grid-item">1</div>
   <div class="grid-item">2</div>
   <div class="grid-item">3</div>
   <div class="grid-item">4</div>
   <div class="grid-item">5</div>
   <div class="grid-item">6</div>
   <div class="grid-item">7</div>
   <div class="grid-item">8</div>
   <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

use display grid for using div instead of table