# How can I create a table without the regular table tag?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

How could I create a table without the `<table>` tag? So it should look exactly like a regular table but without using the common table tags.

Comment: you can use ul li for create or

Comment: Use div.
Create nested div-s. It is so popular in responsive design. You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773186/how-to-use-divs-instead-of-tables Also search google for **css div instead of table**

Answer (score 21):

**2022 Update:**

Please explore CSS flexbox and Grid for implementing table layouts. They are far more flexible than the 2015 answer. https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/

For example: The below code can also be implemented in Flexbox like this:

```css
.table-row {
  display: flex;
  max-width: fit-content;
}

.table-cell {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-row:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      First item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Second item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Third item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fourth item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fifth item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      First item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Second item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Third item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fourth item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fifth item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      First item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Second item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Third item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fourth item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fifth item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2015 Answer:**

You can make use of `CSS tables` which have the same function as `HTML tables`. Learn more about the properties here: [The Anti-hero of CSS Layout - "display:table"](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero). This was introduced in CSS to avoid using `table` tags but not necessarily to avoid using tabular layout. They are still in need for showing up tabular data.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.table-row:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      First item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Second item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Third item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fourth item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fifth item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      First item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Second item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Third item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fourth item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fifth item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      First item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Second item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Third item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fourth item
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Fifth item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a concern with the 2022 Answer. Table flow will be disturbed If one cell of row has larger content.

Comment: Good point. There are examples in that article linked to get around them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ul li` like this.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul style="list-style: none outside none;">
    <li style="float: left;display: block;width: 100px;height: 40px;">Field 1</li>
    <li style="float: left;display: block;width: 100px;height: 40px;">Field 2</li>
    <li style="float: left;display: block;width: 100px;height: 40px;">Field 3</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And please avoid using inline styles. Set separate CSS classes for them.

Answer (score 5):

You can create using div. And Make it easy responsive.

Use `display:table` for it.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.table-col {
  float: left;
  display: table-column;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-col">1</div>
    <div class="table-col">2</div>
    <div class="table-col">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-col">a</div>
    <div class="table-col">b</div>
    <div class="table-col">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```